# List the names and paths of .js and .css in a Web Application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7, log4j2

I have a web application where I usually load .js and .css file thru CDN. However, I want to store them locally and load them locally. I was just curious, if using Spring MVC framework (and tomcat 7 as a web/servlet container), and setting log level to ALL in log4j2, I can see the names and paths of .js and .css files that my web application picked up? 
Currently my web application is working perfectly fine and the idea behind storing .js and .css files locally is that it may speed up loading time of my web application. So right now I am only interested in knowing what my web application has picked up.

Thanks for the help